# Type erasure not working

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

As per the [this generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html):

> During the type erasure process, the Java compiler erases all type
>   parameters and replaces each with its first bound if the type
>   parameter is bounded, or Object if the type parameter is unbounded.

I took the same class as in tutorial and compiled it, and then decompiled it and saw that type parameters are not replaced, so for a moment I thought may be decompilation has re-introduced the type parameters so I used `javap` and I see below o/p, so clearly type parameters are not replaced.

```
C:\>javap Node
Compiled from "Node.java"
public class Node<T> {
  public Node(T, Node<T>);
  public T getData();
}
```

Did I understood the type erasure concept incorrectly or I missed something?

Comment: Also see: [Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens), it goes into a lot more detail.

Comment: But tutorial says "*the Java compiler erases all type parameters*", this means final output of compiler would not have type parameters.